# Escape string problem on <ColGroup> section

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a html code and using `String Builder` going to create a table.I've used thisone inside .cs file. in the below line escape string in colgroup section not working.
[image]

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;width:100 %;\"border=\"1"><colgroup><col style=\"width:50 %;\"><col style=\"width:50 %;\"></colgroup>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello my friend when you need to use " in string u can change with this ' and it's working to HTML
and you can write $ or @ before string which doesn't need to write this '.
sorry me because my English is bad.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"<table style='border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;' border='1'><colgroup><col style='width:50%;'><col style='width:50%;'></colgroup></table>");
    }
```